# Download s3 file only if upload completed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

At the moment I get a list of files from s3 by a prefix and download them.
I want to make sure the file uploaded completely before I start the download.

How is that possible?

```
bucket='bucket-name'
prefix='files_prefix')

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)['Contents']

for key in objs:
    # need to add an if here to check if file upload completed
    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key['Key'],'{}/{}'.format('./data/',key['Key']))
```

Comment: *"need to add an if here to check if file upload completed"* - do you? Have you ever seen / downloaded a file that was not fully uploaded yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such concept as a partially uploaded object. Objects in Amazon S3 are *immutable*. They either exist in full, or do not exist at all.

Multi-part uploads consist of individual uploads (to which the above rule applies), but once the multi-part upload is completed, they convert into a single object with all required parts.

So... you don't need to do anything.